# Does IDLE have a location for temporarily saving works in progress?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-idle

I was writing some code in IDLE for Python 3.8 on Mac OSX when it became non-responsive. Unfortunately it had been some time since my last save and I'd like to not lose my data.

Before I force quit IDLE, I'm wondering if the file I was working on can be found in some kind of temporary folder? I don't think there is an autosave feature (or if there is I didn't know about it). But I'm hoping that it's still writing the contents of my unsaved work to disk somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: I wish IDLE can do that handy feature as TeXStudio https://www.texstudio.org/: I can run/compile code without saving with a name; I can find some recent code by typing `%temp%` on the command line Windows+R (yes, I am usíng Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. No.  Unless you have a program that can access the memory of other programs, it is likely gone.

When I start a new file, I immediately save it under a new name.  I usually run it after any significant editing to check for SyntaxErrors and runtime NameErrors.  My fingers are too twitchy to want to run a hundred new lines at a time.  If I already have tests, then I save and run them often to check the progress in passing the tests.